Try SSR in React js or use Next js?
I wanted to create a React app , but the issue I am facing is the absence of Server Side Rendering (SSR) in React JS, which is important for SEO, sitemap, and indexing of pages in an app. I searched for many tutorials that could guide me on how to implement server-side rendering in React JS.
However, none of them really worked for me. Some of them are so outdated that they’re causing errors.
At this point, I want to know what I should do.
Is there a latest method to implement SSR in React JS? Or should I just switch to NextJS?
I have seen a repository on GitHub where someone has created a MERN blog app and successfully indexed the pages of the application on Google. Here’s the link:
https://github.com/sahandghavidel/mern-blog
However, I am unable to understand what they actually did in this project to index the pages on google

Bro, use NextJS because SSR with react is not stable till now and NextJS offers SSR in easy and stable way. And also next js provides many out of the box things so you should definately try it.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
